# Is it possible to know how many bytes have been printed to a file stream such as standard output?

Tags: c, unix, file, size, stdout

Is it possible for a caller program in C to know how many bytes it has printed to a file stream such as `stdout` without actually counting and adding up the return values of `printf`?

I am trying to implement control of the quantity of output of a C program which uses libraries to print, but the libraries don't report the amount of data they have printed out.

I am interested in either a general solution or a Unix-specific one.

Comment: "a caller program in C" -- What does that mean? "how many bytes it has printed" -- What is "it"? Please state clearly what the components and their relationships are.

Comment: @Jim: "a caller program in C" means "a program written in C which calls functions such as `printf` to print output on `stdout`". "How many bytes it has printed" means "how many bytes the program in C which calls functions such as `printf` to print output on `stdout` has printed".

Comment: You say you want to control the quantity of output ... does that mean that you have a loop and want to exit the loop when you have written too much? And you're writing to a pipe? I think you may be screwed.

Comment: No, this is a web program and I want to know how much the program has output. In the end I fixed this by just making an approximate function.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX-specific: redirect `stdout` to a file, flush after all writing is done, then stat the file and look at `st_size` (or use the `ls` command).

**Update**: You say you're trying to control the quantity of output of a program. The POSIX `head` command will do that. If that's not satisfactory, then state your requirements clearly.

Comment: The trouble is that I don't have that luxury of writing to a file.

Comment: @Master You're wasting your own time and everyone else's if you don't state your requirements in your question. Why can't you write to a file? You said you're writing to a pipe -- so use tee.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. The question I have is whether there is any way of knowing how many bytes have been output to stdout which can be read from the file stream. I want to make a very fast response to the user, and I want to check every single time how many bytes were sent, so I don't have the luxury of writing the output into a file and stating the file etc.

Comment: @Master "feel that way"? It's a basic fact -- stating your requirements gets relevant answers, not doing so wastes time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how reliable this is, but you can use `ftell` on stdout:

```
long int start = ftell(stdout);
printf("abcdef\n");
printf("%ld\n", ftell(stdout) - start); // >> 7
```

EDIT
Checked this on Ubuntu Precise: it does not work if the output goes to the console, but does work if it is redirected to a file.

```
$ ./a.out 
abcdef
0
$ ./a.out >tt
$ cat tt
abcdef
7
$ echo `./a.out`
abcdef 0
$ echo `cat tt`
abcdef 7
```

Comment: Maybe because it is writing to a pipe.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? Driveby downvoter: please identify yourself and say what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: Is this UNIX specific ? ftell( stdout ) seems to always return 0 on windows.

Comment: ***It does not work if output is directed to the console but it works if it is redirected to a file.*** Wrapped this code into a main() function and run it: it prints 0 rather than 7 on Ubuntu Precise, but it writes "abcdef\n7" to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather a heavyweight solution, but the following will work:

1. Create a pipe by calling `pipe()`
2. Spawn a child process
3. In the parent: redirect `stdout` to the write-side of the pipe, and close the read side (and the old `stdout`)
4. In the child: keep reading from the read side of the pipe, and copying the data to the inherited `stdout` (which is the original `stdout`) - counting it as it goes past
5. In the parent, keep writing to `stdout` (which is now the pipe) as usual
6. Use some form of IPC to communicate the result of the count from the child to the parent.

Basically the idea is to spawn a child process, and pipe all output through it, and have the child process count all the data as it goes through.

The precise form of IPC to use may vary - for example, shared memory (with atomic reads/writes on each side) would work well for fast transfer of data, but other methods (such as sockets, more pipes etc) are possible, and offer better scope for synchronisation.

The trickiest part is the synchronisation, i.e. ensuring that, at the time the child tells the parent how much data has been written, it has already processed all the data that the parent said (and there is none left in the pipe, for example). How important this is will depend on exactly what your aim is - if an approximate indication is all that's required, then you may be able to get away with using shared memory for IPC and not performing any explicit synchronisation; if the total is only required at the end then you can close `stdout` from the parent, and have the child indicate in the shared memory when it has received the `eof` notification.

If you require more frequent readouts, which must be exact, then something more copmlex will be required, but this can be achieved by designing some sort of protocol using sockets, pipes, or even condvars/semaphores/etc in the shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

printf returns the number of bytes written.

Add them up.

Comment: Don't forget to not add in the negative numbers returned on a failure.

Comment: -1. This answer is unhelpful and annoying. I specifically asked if it was possible to do this without counting return values from printf. The reason being that my program calls a library which uses fwrite to write the data. And the library does not return how many bytes it has written.